# @Autowire null inside a servlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

the service inside this servlet is null if I use @Autowired, it works fine using context.getBean(); furthermore the mapping with /floorOperationWS/ is not done, I have to define the mapping inside web.xml.

```
package com.confloorapp.services.endpoint;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;



@WebServlet(value = "/floorOperationWS/")
public class UpdateFloorEventServlet extends HttpServlet {


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());


            FloorService floorService = (DoorService)context.getBean("floorService");

}



}
```

Here applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd">

    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered 
        as Spring beans. For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the 
        correct base-package -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.confloorapp" />
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming 
        model. Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only! -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Load Hibernate related configuration -->
    <!-- Here you can also add spring security context, if exist -->
    <import resource="hibernate-context.xml" /> 
    <import resource="spring-security.xml" />

</beans>
```

Comment: Why do you think it should be anything other than `null` if you use `@Autowired`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the servlet is not handled by the Spring container, the autowired annotation does not work out of the box. To overcome this, you can Autowire all the Spring beans in your servlet as shown below:

```
public class UpdateFloorEventServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Autowired
    private FloorService floorService;

    private WebApplicationContext springContext;

    @Override
    public void init(final ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        springContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(config.getServletContext());
        final AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory = springContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        beanFactory.autowireBean(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

}
```

Now the FloorService object will be properly Autowired by Spring and not have a null value.

The spring context file must contain all bean definitions when the bean is used by the application.

On a side note, the init method itself can be implemented in a separate Servlet class which will extend HttpServlet. Then you can have all Servlets extend that class, so they can all use the init method thus avoiding code duplication.